# Changing path of SMSvcHost.exe to .Net 4 version

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp

I have a wcf service which uses net tcp binding ,It works on most of the systems but for few systems it gives metadata exchange error while connecting.

I figured out the cause for it is Net. Tcp listener adapter service.It started on both type of systems but for not working ones its pointing to SMSvcHost.exe of different .Net version.My WCF service is targeting .NET 4 but Net. Tcp listener adapter service is pointing to

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMSvcHost.exe
```

How can I change the path for this service.I tried enabling and disabling WCF non http activation from control panel but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the correct version of .NET installed on the systems that show the error?

Comment: Yes all systems has 4.0 installed,still it points to older version.